# Ruby on rails error with log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I changed some things in my files and when a user is being created instead of going to user/1 it is going to user.1. Any idea why this is happening?
Below is print of log extract.
Thanks,

```
Started GET "/user.113" for 95.45.98.59 at 2016-04-18 23:39:53 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UserController): activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in const_get'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:inblock in constantize' activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in each'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:ininject' activesupport (4.2.2)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? What were the changes you made? Post your route file.

Comment: What does your users controller look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a route helper method, and you want to route to the url for a specific resource, make sure you call `resource_path(resource)` and not `resources_path(resource)`. Note the singular/plural distinction in the route method.

If I understand your question correctly, your controller should look something like this;

```
class UsersController < ApplicationConroller
  # ... 

  def create
    # Create the user...
    if @user.valid?
      redirect_to user_path(@user)  # redirects to `show` action
    else
      render :new   # There are errors, so render the form with errors
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```